# Spring web: Controllers with annotated mappings - Getting HttpServletRequest / form data

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a controller mapped using annotations; the URL is being accessed by the client app and it sends POST / GET data. How do I access the request object in this method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add an argument of type `HttpServletRequest` to the method.

Check 13.11.4. Supported handler method arguments and return types in [the spring mvc docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html)

so:

```
public String yourMethod(HttpServletRequest request) {..}
```

You can use specific request parameters the following way:

```
public String yourMethod(@RequestParam("petId") int petId) {..}
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah I found it as well. :-)

Comment: At least as of Spring 3.0 ("petId") is optional, since it will default to the variable name.

Comment: @stivlo - true, I'm always using it without it, but if debug information is not included by the compiler, spring can't know the name of the param.